# Labels per sentence to per article

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a corpus of articles labelled with levels say {1,2,3}. Now, I extracted some features of text but they are sentence level features. To prepare the dataset for ML training how should I label the sentences, shall I have the labels of each sentence from one article to be the label of the article, or is there any other best approach to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad- what kind of sentence features are we talking about? And what is your ML procedure? If your features are sentence vectors, it would make sense to treat a document as a sequence of sentences (i.e. a 2nd order tensor) and use a recurrent network to manage the classification.

Comment: Hello konstantinoskokos I am estimating the readability difficulty level of an article for which I have extracted POS features of a sentence and some other sematic features but these are per sentence, aa per the goal I need to estimate for whole article let us tell if I am using svm or RF algos. How could I label the senentences from a particular labeled article. To form the dataset for training the algorithms.